# How to read all output from CMD for logs

Tags: java, logging

I have no idea how to make this work but here is the question. I am going to make a program that is going to do a bunch of different operations. I plan to output all information including debugging information and all operations complete. If I detect an error I want to close the program and then read all output and create a file with all of it so I can find out what went wrong. I want to read all output from command prompt and write it to a log with the date and time. Please don't mark this as a duplicate because I could not find any similar questions with answers that pertain to this.

Comment: How are you "executing" the different operations? Are they just classes using `System.out`? Are they external commands?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am just going to detect input and say they click on a button and it takes them somewhere, then I will show that in a display window and a log in cmd so I can see exceptions that occur but I want to save all exceptions after termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are some loose lines relevant to your endeavour:

```
public class StartProcess {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("the app command");
        final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        final OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
        final InputStream err = process.getErrorStream();
        process.waitFor(); // wait for termination
        final int exitCode = process.exitValue();
    }
}
```

However, you should keep in mind to read the input from the streams asynchronously.